# Facebook OG meta tag doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, tags, meta, head

I have problem with Facebook's OG meta tags.
First of all I am not working with them first time.
Actually during last time (which was first time) everything went pretty well.

Now I am using exactly the same code structure and it's not working and I have no idea why.

Here is part of a code in head

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $nazwa; ?>">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Turborura">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<?
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.turborura.pl/'.$miniatura.'">'
?>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="640">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="360">
<meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $opis; ?>">
```

I am checking how Facebook sees my content in Facebook debugger for developers. And it sees only

```
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Turborura">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.turborura.pl/">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="640">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="360">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
```

Variables are downloading phrases to display from data base.

What is interesting that if I type some random phrases manually instead of variables then Facebook debugger sees them correctly.

You can say that variables aren't downloading correct phrases from data base but I am using them on the same page below in body and they're displaying correctly on website.

Also phrases are downloaded from data base and saved to variables before head so variables in head should already know what to display.

Comment: So what is the URL so we can check?

Comment: E.g. http://turborura.pl/video.php?id=111

Comment: You are right. Your code is wrong somewhere. $nazwa is empty

Comment: Now when I pasted link I can see that website isn't working correctly. It's because content is downloading by ID.

When you click hyperlink inside website everything is working perfectly thanks to GET POST.

But when you paste link there is no GET POST. It has to get id from address in browser. That's why Facebook debugger couldn't recognize what contenct is inside website. I've fixed that and it's working good now, thanks :)